# Is there a way to run an executable from within a service?

Tags: c++, windows, service

I started my service design using the template here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540475(v=vs.85).aspx

and I just want to open notepad to prove that I can do stuff in the service because ultimately I want to run to kick off a batch file in a separate process that will start a nginx server. I then want to run a stop server batch file to stop it. Seems simple enough.

I create a process and run it inside the main of the C++ project (this main registers a service main to be called when the service is started).

Inside visual studio's debugger I see that the createprocess returns fine, and then notepad opens.

I then move that code within the service main that is registered, add in a 30 sec sleep delay, start the service, and then attach visual studio's debugger to the process. I see the code hit my breakpoint on the creation of the notepad process.

Then the create process function returns fine, but for some reason notepad doesn't open.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
if (!CreateProcess(
        "C:\\Windows\\System32\\Notepad.exe",   // No module name (use command line)
        NULL,        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
        )
        )
    {
        printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
    }
```

i got it to run the bat file sucessfully and write a file. had the path set wrong. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Services run under a separate user account with no desktop.  You can run processes perfectly normally, but you cannot show any UI.

Comment: i do the same thing with no gui trying to just run a batch file that runs console programs, but it doesn't work. Is that not allowed either?

Comment: it creates the promise and returns true, but i don't see any output. Let me add the bat file to the opening post.

Comment: I still have one more question though. For some reason it will let me write in the batch file, but it won't let me run the Nginx server execute like I want. Is the network not initialized when windows starts up until a user logs in? can I not run network code under the service user?

Comment: @JamesJoshuaStreet: You don't see the output because the launched console is running on a **different session** than the one that the user is logged in to.  If you want to see the console UI when launched from a service, use [`CreateProcessAsUser()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429.aspx) instead. Use [`WTSEnumerateSessions()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383833.aspx) to find a session in the `WTSActive` state, and then use [`WTSQueryUserToken()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383840.aspx) to get that session's user token.

Comment: @JamesJoshuaStreet: a service can run network code, it is not dependent on a user being logged in. If you are having problems with Nginx, it is likely going to be a problem related to Nginx itself not working in a service session.  Again, try using `CreateProcessAsUser()` to run it in the context of a different session than the service's own session.

Comment: if i create process as user though, how can i have the program run before a user logs on to windows? can I createprocessasUser(Administrator) to run the process before login?

Comment: @JamesJoshuaStreet: no, unless a user is logged on there is no user session you can run a process in.  If the problem is just that Nginx doesn't like running as local system, you can reconfigure the service to run in a real account.  But if Nginx doesn't like running in a service context, there's not much you can do about it.  You might need to ask a separate question about that, although it wouldn't be on-topic here; perhaps Nginx's own support resources?

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://nginx-win.ecsds.eu/
and download Install_nginx_php_services.zip, read the scripts how this works for nginx and php and anything else, sources of the tools used can be found on MS's sites.